# Missing data foreach XML

Tags: php, magento, simplexml

something happening in my script and i cant figure out whats going on, basically i have a array of products, and with this array im populating the items in the foreach loop to a xml file, the problema is that in the first nodes appears empty data, and im sure that i dont have emmpty data in the array, i already tried just printing the data in plaintext and works fine, only when im looping and creating the xml file.

```
My script:
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<products/>');

for ($i = 0; $i <= sizeof($catalog); ++$i) {
    $track = $xml->addChild('product');
    $track->addChild('name', $i . $catalog[$i]["name"]);
    $track->addChild('brand', $catalog[$i]["brand"]);
}

Header('Content-type: text/xml');
print($xml->asXML());
```

Comment: It's going to be difficult without some test data.  Can you create a test of a couple of `$catalog` entries and the XML they produce.

Comment: Please post the output from `print_r($catalog);`. It is rarely helpful to use an incrementing `for` loop in php instead of the `foreach` form which uses the array keys. There could be something faulty with the indexing which the print_r will reveal